# How can I make AllowDBNull work for GUID?

Tags: c#, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, csvhelper

I am using DataColumn to create a new column for a DataTable. I am using `AllowDBNull` to specify that a column can have NULL values.

This works fine except for the case when I have a column with `uniqueidentifier` type where I am doing

```
public static Type GetClrType(SqlDbType sqlType, bool isNullable)
{
  switch (sqlType)
  {
     case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
        return isNullable ? typeof(Guid?) : typeof(Guid);
     ......other types......
  }
}
```

```
DataColumn columnValue = DataColumn(column.Name, GetClrType(columnType, IsNullable))
dt.Columns.Add(columnValue);
```

I am having issues when trying to load the datatable using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper) and seeing the error

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors
> occurred. (Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
> (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).Couldn't store `<NULL>` in
> MyGuIdColumn Column.  Expected type is Guid.)

Any help to solve this is appreciated.

**Update (More details):**

Csv file records are something like this:

```
Id (uniqueidentifier, Not null)      | Name (Nvarchar, null) | OtherId (uniqueidentifier, null) 
deb01846-c208-ec01-a4e4-005056bc1234 | TestName              | NULL
```

I am reading the csv file like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
// get the table def -> will have all column props
foreach (column in columns)
{
  var columnType = column.DataType; // (uniqueidentifier) I get this value from table schema
  var dataType = Map.GetClrType(columnType); // (GUID) from a SqlDbType -> c# map
  DataColumn columnValue = new DataColumn(column.Name, dataType);
  columnValue.AllowDBNull = true; // comes from IS Nullable column of table schema
  columnValue.DefaultValue = if is nullable => Guid.Empty/Null/DbNUll.Value; // tried these
  dt.Columns.Add(columnValue);
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
   using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
   {
      dt.Load(dr); // error here
      return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Share the code which is giving exception

Comment: Updated with more details

Comment: Your schema is marked `NOT NULL`, and you are specifying `typeof(Guid)` (not `typeof(Guid?)`) on the .NET side. Neither of those support NULL

Comment: @Flydog57 updated my post. I do have it the way you mentioned.

Comment: @Flydog57 `DataTable` / `DataColumn` doesn't support C# `Nullable<T>` anyway (as `DataTable` predates C# 2.0). You have to use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` to represent `NULL`.

Comment: Can't help but think that life would be so much easier if you just make a `record X(Guid Id, string Name, Guid? OtherId)` and get CsvHelper to turn your CSV file into a bunch of X..

Comment: Can you use Guid  and skip Guid? altogether ? The 'null' equivalent for Guid can be identified by comparing with Guid.Empty. The actual Null values will be represented by DbNull anyway.

Comment: @MayurEkbote Could you please elaborate on this? I can use Guid and skip Guid?. Doing so, `CsvDataReader` would still complain while reading the NULL values into the datatable as I set the column type to Guid and it cannot be null.

Comment: Try this : https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/inline-type-conversion/

Comment: In the conversion put (t=>String.IsEmptyOrNull(t) ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(t)) . This should work. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: I won't be able to use `RegisterClassMap` because the csv files can be anything and I won't have its info until I start reading. I just know that the tables (csv file name == table name) would exist on the database and that's where I am getting the schema from. LMK if I am misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: If it is all dynamic, can you try "reading by hand?" You can do the type check or conversion here. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh.. It took me a while to see it, but the problem is, I suspect, that your CSV file literally contains the string `"NULL"` in the OtherId column; you have to tell CSVH that "NULL" means `DBNull.Value`

The following code will read the CSV you posted into github:

```
        using var reader = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(_openFileDialog.FileName), conf);
        using var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(reader);

        var dt = dataReader.GetSchemaTable(); //the schema table is huge, get CSVH to make it

        //the schema table describes the file layout
        dt.Rows[0]["DataType"] = typeof(Guid); //first column is a GUID
        dt.Rows[0]["AllowDBNull"] = false;     //and not null (default true)
        dt.Rows[2]["DataType"] = typeof(Guid); //third column is also a GUID

        //tell CSVH that a string of "NULL" is a null value
        var tco = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptions();
        tco.NullValues.Add("NULL");
        reader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<string>(tco);


        var ddt = new DataTable();
        ddt.Load(dataReader);
```

Now ddt contains a Guid column for OtherId, and it's allowing null guids

You don't have to know the column types in advance. By the time the `var dt = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();var dt = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();` line has executed, `dt` will have the column names. If the headers are as you have posted, then by the time you've got the schema, but before you read any data you'll be able to enumerate the schema table and tweak it:

[image]

ps; I cheated a bit with your CSV, because I couldn't be bothered looking up how to set pipe as the delimiter - exercise for the reader(hah):

[image]

Comment: This works great for me. I am now able to load the data. Even though the data is successfully loaded into the table, I am seeing `System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.` in my catch block. I will look into that but my issue is solved now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Check for mills in the primary key column; you can call `ddt.GetErrors` to get all the rows in error and the DataRow itself has a RowError property that tells you what is wrong